# how to select the last characters of a file name in python

Tags: python

Is there any efficient way to select the last characters of a string file Name until there's a Slash / in Python?

For example, I got the following file Name:

```
File=r"C:\Users\folder1\folder2\folder3/fileIwanttoget.txt"
```

I would like to select only the string:

```
string=fileIwanttoget.txt
```

Independently of the number of characters that this file name has.

Comment: Use `split()`, i.e. `File.split("/")[-1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract the file name from a file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113157/how-to-extract-the-file-name-from-a-file-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to split your string, you could do:

```
file_name = r"C:\Users\folder1\folder2\folder3/fileIwanttoget.txt"

ending = file_name.split('/')[-1]
print(ending)
# fileIwanttoget.txt
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on `.split()`. If you prefer working directly with paths, you should consider monkuts answer.

Comment: not the best solution if you run the code in a different operating system

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: It works in this particular example but if you would have a pure windows path `r"C:\Users\folder1\folder2\folder3\fileIwanttoget.txt"` your solution will stop working. `os.path` or `pathlib` suggested by @monkut can deal with OS specific path representations

Comment: Valid point. However, OP was specifically asking how to split the string in his question (on `/`). Moreover, when working with paths you should be using the built-in `pathlib` package instead of `os` from python 3.4 on.

Answer (score 3):

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a modern approach to path handling and makes these tasks easy:

```
from pathlib import Path

f = Path("C:\Users\folder1\folder2\folder3/fileIwanttoget.txt")
f.name
```

> fileIwanttoget.txt

Also, when you have a `Path` object you can *open* it directly:

```
from pathlib import Path

f = Path("C:\Users\folder1\folder2\folder3/fileIwanttoget.txt")
with f.open('r', encoding='utf8') as file_in:
    process(file_in)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the python libraries that deal with file paths. The `os.path` is a good place to look into it.

```py
from os.path import basename
string=basename(File)
```